# Declare object in PHP

Tags: php, object

What is the PHP equivalent of ECMAScript's:

```
var myObject={};
```

*EDIT: I am looking to declare a PHP object.*

Thank you.

Comment: try: `$myObject = new stdClass();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be:

```
$myObject = new stdClass;
```

or:

```
$myObject = (object)NULL;
```

See also http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#92123
and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php

Comment: Thank you, Mario. It looks a bit hackish.

Comment: The typecast is hackish, but the assignment is legit imo.

Comment: I was comparing it to the syntax of JavaScript for example, where it's clear it's an object. Not sure, but by the look of it, `stdClass` could be anything.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually language misappropriation; not a typical idiom. And now that I think about it, the closest equivalent to the JS/ECMAScript object would actually be `new ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS)`.